# Verify vector subspace - closure of addition and scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I hope this isn't a duplicate of another question but I've been trying to find something to help me and nothing has really done the job. I'm trying to verify $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$ by checking for the presence of $0$, the closure of addition and the closure of scalar product. So I have:

$W=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Q} | 3x-5y+z=0\}$, $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ over a field $F=\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously the $0$ vector is present, but I'm not sure how to prove the other two. For closure of addition, I have:

For $v,w\in W$, we need to prove that $v+w\in W$.

If $v=(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and $w=(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$, then

$v+w=(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})+(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})=(x_{1}+x_{2},y_{1}+y_{2},z_{1}+z_{2})$

which is an element of $W$ if and only if

$(z_{1}+z_{2})=-3(x_{1}+x_{2})+5(y_{1}+y_{2})$

I don't know how to continue. The same problem occurs for closure of scalar product, only I have:

$\lambda z=-3\lambda x+5\lambda y$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Q}$

Is there a general way for proving closure of addition and scalar product? I have to solve some more problems like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see that $(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2) \in W$, you have $$3(x_1+x_2) - 5(y_1+y_2) + (z_1+z_2) = 3x_1 - 5y_1 + z_1 + 3x_2 - 5y_2  + z_2 = 0 + 0 = 0,$$
since $(x_1,y_1,z_1) \in W$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2) \in W$.

I will leave the scalar product to you. The idea is the same; use the fact that your "original" element is in W to prove that your "new" element is still in W.